# Error while retrieving and rendering data via datatable plugin

Tags: ajax, datatable, datasource

I'm Using datatable Plugin To Show Them .It Gets Data From a Json Array Of Object Like This

```js
    {
        "id": 19,
        "start_Date": "1399-12-18T00:00:00",
        "start_Time": {
            "ticks": 40800000000,
            "days": 0,
            "hours": 1,
            "milliseconds": 0,
            "minutes": 8,
            "seconds": 0,
            "totalDays": 0.04722222222222222,
            "totalHours": 1.1333333333333333,
            "totalMilliseconds": 4080000,
            "totalMinutes": 68,
            "totalSeconds": 4080
        },
        "end_Time": {
            "value": {
                "ticks": 825600000000,
                "days": 0,
                "hours": 22,
                "milliseconds": 0,
                "minutes": 56,
                "seconds": 0,
                "totalDays": 0.9555555555555556,
                "totalHours": 22.933333333333334,
                "totalMilliseconds": 82560000,
                "totalMinutes": 1376,
                "totalSeconds": 82560
             },
            "hasValue": true
          },
       },
```

As You See There Are Two Field 'start_Time' and 'end_Time' In This Array. While I'm rendering 'start_Time' Field It Has No Error And I Can Access And Rendering It's Value Easily, But When It Comes To Rendering 'end_Time' Field I Get An Error Like This[image]

I Have To Mention That I've Configured It's ajax Parameters Like This

```js
     $("#mytable").DataTable({`enter code here`
                        ajax: {
                            url: "/production/showall/",
                            dataSrc: "",
                            data: { "year": year },
                            method: "GET"
                        },
                        columns: [
                            { data: "batch_Nu" },
                            {..... },
                            {
                                data: "start_Time",
                                render: function (data, type, row) {
                                    if (data != 'null') {
                                        return ('0' + data.hours).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + data.minutes).slice(-2);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        return data;
                                        //return "null";
                                    }
                                      },
                            {
                                     data: "end_Time",
                                render: function (data, type, row) {
                                        //debugger;
                                    if (data != 'null') {
                                        return (('0' + data.value).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' +row).slice(-2));
                                    }
                                    else {

                                        return 'Null';
                                    }
                                    }
                                    }
```

Could You Please Tell Me What Is Wrong With this Code.Thanks.

Comment: Observation: this looks odd: `('0' + data.value)`. You have assigned `end_Time` to `data` using this: `data: "end_Time"`. Therefore `data.value` evaluates to an object `{...}`, which contains `"ticks": 825600000000,` and so on... When you concatenate this object with `'0'`, I would expect you to end up with a string containing `0[object Object]`. That is not what you want, I assume. Do you need to drill down further? `('0' + data.value.hours)`, or something like that?

Comment: Or, perhaps you can assign `end_Time.value` to the `data` option: `data: "end_Time.value"`. Then you can use `('0' + data.hours)`. Either way, you can use `console.log()` statements to see what intermediate values are, to help with your own debugging.

Comment: @anderewjames thanks for your answer but i,ve try out all the possible case like data.value.hour or assign data to end_Time.value but none of them worked

Answer (score 0):

I can use your JSON data with no errors if I make the following changes to your `columns` definitions:

1. For your first column (`start_Time`), there is a missing closing brace. I assume this is a copy/paste error, because otherwise you would not get this column to display - and you mention in the question that it displays OK.
2. For your second column (`end_Time`), I changed the `data` option to use `"end_Time.value"`, for the reasons given in my comments in the question.
3. In the second column, I changed `('0' + data.value)` to `('0' + data.hours)` for the reasons given in my comments in the question.
4. In the second column you have `('0' +row)`. I am not sure what this is intended to do - but I replaced it with `('0' + data.minutes)` to match how the first column works. The value of `row` is an object containing all the values in `"end_Time"`, so trying to use it with `'0'` does not make sense, for the reasons given in my comments in the question.

After making the above changes I can see `01:08` in column 1 and `22:56` in column 2.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I am not sure if this is what you want - but it works - so you should be albe to make additional changes as needed, to get exactly what you need.

Here is the full `columns` section:

```js
  columns: [
    {
      data: "start_Time",
      render: function (data, type, row) {
        if (data != 'null') {
          return ('0' + data.hours).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + data.minutes).slice(-2);
        } else {
          return data;
          //return "null";
        }
      }
    },
    {
      data: "end_Time.value",
      render: function (data, type, row) {
      //debugger;
        if (data != 'null') {
          return (('0' + data.hours).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + data.minutes).slice(-2));
        } else {
          return 'Null';
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

If you are still not able to resolve your problem, then I suspect there is something else going on, the details for which may be missing from the question.

So, for example, when I used your test data, I made sure it was placed in an array `[...]`. I assume your actual data already has this - since it is mentioned in the question.

---

**Update**

1. Please do not post questions in the "answers" section. If you want to provide additional information, you can edit your question, and add the extra information there. After doing that, you should delete your answer.
2. Your DataTable definition is good.  When I use your data and your DataTable definition, the data is displayed with no errors.

[image]

3. The problems start after the end of the DataTables definition, from `flag = true;` to the second-to-last `});`.

This is the section of code I am referring to:

```
});


//flag = true;
//}
//else {
//  $("#mytable").DataTable().ajax.url("/production/showall/?year=" + year + "").load();
//}
//});
//});


} );
```

If you comment-out the exact same lines that I did here, you should see your table data, with no errors.

The commented-out code is messy.

3a) It starts with `flag = true;`, which you don't use anywhere.

3b) After that, there is an extra closing `}` which does not have a corresponding opening `{`.

3c) Then there is an `else` statement - but where is the related `if` statement? It is missing.

4. I don't know what you are trying to do with the final `load()` line of code, because these other errors have broken the structure of your JavaScript code.

**A good technique for debugging this type of problem is to start from nothing, and then gradually add in one small piece at a time: One column of data *and nothing else at all*. Make sure that works. Then add a little bit more, and test again. Then repeat this process until you break something. Then you will know exactly where the problem lies.**

I am sure you will be able to finish debugging and fixing this for yourself, from this point onward. If you do get stuck with a new problem, you can ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I shorted code for abbreviation . I thought that makes no different.

Comment: I added more notes to my answer.

Comment: thamks dear friend. flag property is somthing related to a dropdown list that chose the year and after the page is loaded the flag is false then datatable would not work.as the dropdown list chosen the flag will be true

Comment: Dear friend I've done all the things you mentioned but I'm still getting error.the wired thing is when I run in debugging mode and put watch on the property, the value of it will be shown properly but at last time it turn to undifined !